# Web fonts not rendered on Firefox

Tags: firefox, fonts, truetype-fonts, font-faces

I'm on Firefox 42.0 and web fonts (icons) are not rendered for FontAwesome framework :

[image: Font Awesome]

or on Github :

[image: GitHub]

And many others websites.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried to figure out where this came from by comparing `pref.js` file from a clean install of Firefox and i have found the property that caused the issue :

```
user_pref("layers.acceleration.disabled", true);
```

The value have to be on `false` to solve this issue.
Hope this help.